# Single toggle button in angularjs to switch ON/OFF

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I have two different labels. I want it to work on toggle slider button.
This is my code:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="save">   
  <label href="#pre_sum" 
         for="id_url"
         data-toggle="modal" 
         class="btn btn-default btn-on btn-lg" 
         ng-click="getdata()" 
         id="saveOn">
    ON
  </label>
  <label id="devicesStatusId" 
         class="btn btn-default btn-off btn-lg" 
         style="color:#fff;background-color:#DA4F49" 
         id="saveOff"
         ng-click="changeDeviceStatus();" 
         id="devicesStatusId">
    OFF
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: kindly help someone with solution in slider button

Comment: I don't know anything about AngularJS. I got here because of the `PHP` tag ...

Comment: _have you tried turning it off an on again?_

Comment: please clear your question little more.

Comment: yes its working turn on and off

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a direct Angular.js answer but I can help you clear up the **logic** (at least how I would do it) with a little vue.js + a description. But please make sure you edit your question so it describes what you're trying to do, people don't like shallow questions.

Also I'm not sure why your labels have multiple ids?

**Example**

```
<label v-if="labelOn" @click="toggleLabel"> On! </label>
<label v-else @click="toggleLabel"> Off! </label>

<script>
new Vue({
    data: {
        labelOn: false;
    },
    method: {
        toggleLabel()
        {
            if(this.labelOn == true){
                this.labelOn = false;
            } else {
                this.labelOn = true;
            }
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

**Description**

The script is very simple let me explain the the vue.js functions first then i'll go over the logic.

The `v-if` attribute on the labels is basically saying "if this value is true, the show this" so in this case if labelOn is true then show the first label or else show the second one, hence the `v-else`, quite simple.

the `@click` attribute is basically saying when you click this label, do this function. Simple enough, the function called is `toggleLabel` on both labels.

Now the toggle label function just changes the value of `labelOn` from true to false and vice versa. Altogether the logic here is:

- When you click the label, fire the `toggleLabel` function in the vue.js script
- The `toggleLabel` function then checks to see if the value of the `labelOn` variable is true or false, if true flip to false, if false flip to true.
- The `v-if` attribute on the labels now checks the value of `labelOn` and hides / shows the correct label depending on that.

Hopefully you can apply that logic to vue.js, I know that most of the time that I'm developing my problem is simply the logic behind the activity that I'm trying to do so hopefully this clears some things up.

Comment: thank you this helps me but i have to do it on single toggle button which slides on or off

Comment: @VishnuJoshi you can apply this to that situation, it will work the same way just move the onclick attribute to the button and go from there. Also explain your problem more in depth it will help people understand whats wrong!